# How to change texture setting of displacement?

Tags: texturing, displacement, bump

I've upgraded to 2.82 and found that something in the shading tab has changed. I can't find the displacement settings.

[image: 1]

so that all my displacement becomes 'bump only', how can I fix this?

I don't quite know if this is caused by a plugin.

here's all plugin I have:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to switch your render engine to "Cycles" in the render properties. True displacement is not available with Eeevee (yet?).